# XHTML font browser compatibility in IE9

Tags: html, css, web, xhtml, frontend

I have a link in the xhtml file which is working fine (mouse hover) in IE8, But when I open the same page in IE9 and when I mouse hover on the link the font size is increasing.

Can some one tell me why is it happening?

Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
              "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
 <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; xmlns:h="java.sun.com/jsf/html";
  xmlns:c="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; xmlns:ui="java.sun.com/jsf/facelets";
  xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core"; xmlns:p="primefaces.org/ui"; class="no-js">
<head>
 <script src="js/modernizr-1.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

But it didn't work -:(

Comment: Did you try using Modernizr?

Comment: Can you share the XHTML file? Without seeing it, we're just guessing.

Comment: @Dillmo -  i did added Modernizer after see ur comment, below is the code were an dhow i added it.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" class="no-js">
   <head>
   <script src="C:/Desktop/modernizr-1.0.min.js"></script>
   </head>

Comment: @tom Can you add that to the question? That would be much easier to read.

Comment: @MrLister - i did added the code but some how it is not showing up in my post??

Comment: i did tried adding  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"  />
   </head> but it dint worked either

Comment: I formatted the code for you. But it doesn't contain a single link; I'm afraid you have to show more. There are some errors in it though; those semicolons shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the font file on the same domain as your site? If not...

```
IE and Firefox implement the same origin policy, so any font library served 
on a different domain from the page will not be downloaded unless using CORS.
```

Click on 'Known Issues'...

http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface